# on an infinite complex Hilbert space .

Tags: complex-analysis

On an infinite complex Hilbert space. Let A\in B(H) then 1. If A is positive, then log(A) is positive too. 2. If A is self-adjoint, then so is log(A). 3. If A is normal, then log(A) is normal. 4. If A is compact, then log(A) is compact. 5. If A is quasinormal, then so is log(A). Note: log denote the principal logarithm.

Comment: Definition of $\log (A)$?.  Two possibilities: $|A|<1:   \log (1-A)= \sum \frac {1}{n} A^n $  or $A$ diagonalizable positive $\text{diag}(\log(a_{1,1}) \dots = U^+ \log (A) U$

Comment: Every Hilbert space (other than $\{0\}$) is infinite.

Comment: Presumably "infinite" is supposed to be "infinite-dimensional", and  this is using the holomorphic functional calculus, if possible, or the continuous functional calculus if $A$ is normal.  But what if $A$ is not invertible?